# How to pass arguments to anonymous lambda function in Kotlin?

Tags: lambda, parameter-passing, kotlin, anonymous-function

I'd like to write an anonymous lambda function in Kotlin, but it looks like it  doesn't take the argument passed to it. (It is not passed at all, since the IDE hints that "*variable 'name' is never used*".)

Code:

```
var name = "Tobias Boon"
println("reverse=" + fun(name: String): String {
    var t: String = ""
    for(i in name.indices.last downTo 1) {
        t += text.subSequence(i - 1, i)
    }
    return t
})
```

Currently prints: `reverse=(kotlin.String) -> kotlin.String`

Comment: You arent passing any argument to the function. You are defining a function, and not calling it.

Comment: I know, I denoted it the description.

Comment: I've read it. What's the problem then? What is your expected output?

Comment: I'd like to know how to pass that argument to the lambda... The desired input would be like this would produce `println(name.reversed())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never call the function with the parameter, it should be

```
val name = "Tobias Boon"
println("reverse=" + fun(name: String) : String {
   ...
      return t
}(name))
```

Btw, your particular example is already implemented in the standard library:

```
println(name.reversed())
```

Comment: Thanks, that was I looking for! "name.reversed()" are you trolling me with this? :)

Comment: I know. My intention with this code was to learn about lambdas, not to reverse strings.